# Local Users and Groups on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: sharepoint, users

I'm running Windows Sharepoint Services on server 2008. It's not connected to an AD so I'm using local users on the machine.

When inside SharePoint and browsing for users I see all users, can I restrict this so that a given user sees only users in a given group?

Hope that makes sense

K

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter  property setter to create a customer filter for the people picker. Details on its use can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263452.aspx).

For example, you could filter it on the users email:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -url http://sharepoint/sites 
-pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv (mail=*@email.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

[Filtering Active Directory Accounts from People Picker](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/teameli/archive/2007/11/21/filtering-active-directory-accounts-from-people-picker.aspx)

Also, the following command can also be used:

```
stsadm -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "ou=...., dc=..."
```

Comment: This will only work with Active directory, which the OP says he does not have.

Comment: The first link is the same as your answer...

Comment: true, hadn't seen that, but the command you give could cause confusion as its only useful for AD installations

Comment: Jsut added the second one for completeness

Comment: So are we saying this could be used as a solution? :)

Comment: I guess so (the first link anyway in your case :-D)

Comment: All these suggestions seem AD related unless I am missing something? My  users are local server users. Cheers K